# Unexpected behavior of layout_constraintDimensionRatio

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

As far as I know if I use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1` in an element, the height of that element will be fixed and then the width will adapt to be same size as the width, but in the following example the height is not fixed.

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/gd"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I expected to happen:

[image]

What is really happening:

[image]

**Curious fact**

If I add another view with the same `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` next to the view I had (forming an horizontal chain of two views) the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` is now working as expected mysteriously.

Code with two views now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/gd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/v2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/gd"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/v1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/gd"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Extected and what is really happening:

[image]

Now my question is why if I have a single view `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` is not working as expected but if I add a second view forming an horizontal chain with first view `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` is now working?

Answer (score 0):

The `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"` means the **H**eight should respect that aspect ratio *after* setting the **W**idth.

In your example, you have set both sides Start and End to parent. So width should be math parent. Now Height will be as much as the width.

In second example, you have limited its widths. And **H**eight will respect to the ratio.

Try to change `H` to `W` in first example and see what happens. (You have limited Height instead of width)

Comment: In second example if I remove both app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" the width is the half of the screen for both Views, then why app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" is changing the width if you have said that first the width is set and later th height will respect the ratio ?

Comment: Constraint layout is not stupid. If it knows there is no way to apply logic, it will do the only possible way. (Here the ratio says it should be 1:1, but he tries to make the width as big as possible, but the height won't let him go any further.)

Comment: Yes but if that was true, why in first example even if the max height of the view is limited by the guideline when using app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1" the guideline is ignored and the height exceeds that limit ? I am referring to the second image (the one that is below "What is really happening:")

Comment: In the complicated situation the conditions become more complicated. In first example left and right (for obtaining width) are free to parent. but in the second example one side of each views is constrained to parent but other side is free. so layout cannot determine the exact width. Also you have created a chain! connecting end to start. if you don't specify the chain style, it choose spread style by default.

Comment: I wonder why you don't want to follow CL structure? If you want specify width first so try to limit width and not height. then use `H, 1:1` everything else are accidental or complicated to explain.